# Solr deep paging with cursorMark - memory/cpu impact for large result sets?

Tags: solr

I'm looking into using Solr for a use case that will require some deep paging, thinking an upper bound of about 100k total results split into 1k pages from a collection of ~10 million records. I quickly discovered why using start & num_rows is a bad idea for a result set that size and came across cursorMark in the process. Articles I've found about cursorMark suggest a relatively constant time for record access regardless of position in the set which seems perfect for my case.

The question I had though, is there any kind of performance impact going down this route? Is there any performance difference in terms of memory/CPU usage for using cursorMark to deep page into result sets of 1k, 10k, 100k, 1 million records assuming I return back 1000 at time?

Answer (score 1):

In theory it gets a little bit faster as you page down. In reality the difference is so small that you won't not notice it.

A standard non-cursor search uses a little queue to hold the top-X results. Every match is added to that queue, pushing out poorer matches if the queue is full.

A cursor-search also uses a queue of size X. Every match is added to that queue, *if* their sort value is beyond the previous cursor mark, pushing out poorer matches if the queue is full. So as you page deeper, there are a bit less inserts.

There are some very illustrative graphs of cursor performance at https://lucidworks.com/blog/2013/12/12/coming-soon-to-solr-efficient-cursor-based-iteration-of-large-result-sets/

Comment: Can you please provide source for the information which you have provided above?

Comment: Sure: https://lucidworks.com/blog/2013/12/12/coming-soon-to-solr-efficient-cursor-based-iteration-of-large-result-sets/